# Installing attic stairs

Tags: construction

I want to install attic stairs. The rough opening is 30x44 when measured to the wall. Or 30x51 if measured to the end of the opening. Most attic stairs are 30x54. Is there a way to install the stairs with these differences is measurement?  What would I need to do?

Comment: What wall? Please describe your scenario in detail or, better, provide a photo. Welcome to SE.

Comment: Sounds like the RO straddles a wall; effectively reducing it 30x44. Don't forget that it might need operating clearance and it certainly needs a few inches for the trim but you can cut off the part of the trim that would go along the wall.

Answer (score 3):

If the existing opening is not large enough for the stairs dimensions you will need to enlarge the opening.  This work is for advanced DIY-er's that are comfortable with altering buildings' framing and than patching the sections that are modified.

It may be best if you search for folding stairs smaller or exactly of the dimensions the present opening measures.

Comment: Agreed, one or the other: a bigger opening or smaller stairs.